# In how many ways can the committee be selected if the girls must include either Roberta or Priya but not both?

Tags: permutations, combinations

A committee of three boys and three girls is to be selected from a class of $14$ boys and $17$ girls. In how many ways can the committee be selected if the girls must include either Roberta or Priya but not both?

I did $(14 C 3) \times (15 C 2) \times 2 = 76,440$

However, the correct answer is $65,520$.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of posting 3 (or more!) related questions, post one question, wait until you get an answer you understand, then try to solve the other questions on your own; if this doesn't work, post one more question, and iterate the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

**Your answer is correct.**

Just to confirm, here is another way with a longer, clumsier count for girls.

[All combos - combos with neither of R or P - combos with both of R & P]

= **$^{14}C_3\cdot [^{17}C_3 - ^{15}C_3 - ^{15}C_1$]** = 76,440